# Using ggplot2 to graph a set of data

Tags: r, ggplot2

New addition to my old post:

I apologize if it seemed as though I was expecting anyone to do the work for me! That definitely was not my intention.

using dput, the output gave me the following:

```
    structure(list(Reported.Behavior = structure(c(3L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 
8L, 7L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("Alcohol-marijuana", "Depression/Suicidal Ideation", 
"Homophobic Teasing", "Parent Communication", "Parent Support", 
"Peer Victimization", "Racism", "School climate"), class = "factor"), 
    Heterosexual.Mean = c(0.2, 0.45, 0.63, 0.8, 1.79, 0.61, 1.89, 
    3.31), Heterosexual.SD = c(0.66, 0.75, 0.67, 0.97, 0.49, 
    0.67, 0.95, 0.65), Questioning.Mean = c(0.84, 0.95, 1.07, 
    1.36, 1.63, 1.03, 1.79, 2.83), Questioning.SD = c(1.33, 1.18, 
    0.95, 1.51, 0.65, 0.82, 1.13, 0.93), LGB.Mean = c(0.57, 0.56, 
    0.77, 1, 1.72, 0.82, 1.84, 3.14), LGB.SD = c(1.13, 0.9, 0.82, 
    1.16, 0.56, 0.76, 1.07, 0.8), ANOVA.F.Value = c(375.94, 166.54, 
    176.54, 138.82, 49.13, 193.31, 5.63, 231.73), ANOVA.Effect.Size = c(0.05, 
    0.03, 0.03, 0.02, 0.01, 0.03, 0, 0.03)), .Names = c("Reported.Behavior", 
"Heterosexual.Mean", "Heterosexual.SD", "Questioning.Mean", "Questioning.SD", 
"LGB.Mean", "LGB.SD", "ANOVA.F.Value", "ANOVA.Effect.Size"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

I have tried various ggplot commands, such as the following: (my data set name = lgbtq)

ggplot(All.Means, aes(Mean.Values, Homophobic.Teasing, color = Mean.Values)) + geom_bar()

However, this only produces a graph for the Homophobic Teasing Means. I am trying to find a way to put all of the behavior means on the same graph (i.e., side-by-side bars, color-coded by sexuality)

I have tried to manipulate the data by producing csv files that only contain one behavior. For example:

```
ggplot(data = Peer.Victimization.Means, aes(x = Mean.Values, y = Peer.Victimization, color = Mean.Values)) + geom_bar(color = "black", fill = "red")
```

Which works, however, I would like to find a way to utilize the entire data set, as is.

I have seen posts referring to the 'melt' function, but haven't been successful with this yet. :/ Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

This is my first time using "R" so please know that I am very much a beginner. For a course assignment I am using a data set that has the following column titles:

Reported Behavior (includes 8 different behavior names)
Heterosexual Mean (includes a value for each behavior)
Questioning Mean (includes a value for each behavior)
LGB Mean (includes a value for each behavior)

I would like to use ggplot2 to graph this data. It would be ideal if I could produce a bar graph that has the following:

Y Axis: "Mean Value"
X Axis: "Reported Behavior", for each reported behavior, I would like to have 3 separate bars, side by side (Heterosexual Mean value, Questioning Mean value, and LGB Mean value). Then, it would be ideal if I could color code these.

So, overall, the Y axis represents the Mean values, and the X axis lists all reported behaviors, each with 3 bars comparing the 3 different sexualities. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!!!!

Jessie

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Generally speaking SO members are more willing to answer questions when they can see that the person asking has made an effort to solve the problem. Asking SO to basically do all your work for you is not OK. So the first step you should take is to show us what R code you have already written by editing/adding to your question above. The second step is to show us (part of) your data. The `dput` function is useful; type `?dput` at the R prompt for help. See also [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: In addition, if you need more help to get the basics of R and ggplot2, talk to your course supervisor. It is their work to help you learn the basics.

Answer (score 2):

Rearrange data:

```
library(reshape2)
mdat <- melt(dat[,1:7]) ## Drop ANOVA vars
mdat <- data.frame(mdat,colsplit(mdat$variable,"\\.",c("type","val")))
cdat <- dcast(mdat,Reported.Behavior+type~val)
```

Draw the picture.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(cdat,aes(x=Reported.Behavior,y=Mean,fill=type))+
    geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")+
    ## ugly!
    ## geom_linerange(aes(ymin=Mean-SD,ymax=Mean+SD),
    ##   position=position_dodge(width=0.9))+
    coord_flip()
```

- `coord_flip()` is nice because it makes it easier to read the labels.
- There is commented-out code here to add lines showing +/-1 SD -- I didn't add them because the SD is so large that the plot is quite ugly -- you should think about that ...
- bar plots are familiar, but `geom_point()` might be prettier (less "non-data-ink" *sensu* Tufte)

[image]